# Why were case guards removed from Elm?

Tags: pattern-matching, elm

Other functional programming languages have this feature, such as OCaml:

```ml
match x with
| Some n when n < 10 -> ...
| Some n when n < 100 -> ...
...
```

or Haskell:

```hs
case x of 
  Just n | n < 10 -> ...
         | n < 100 -> ...
  ...
```

Why was it removed from Elm? (Earlier versions apparently had it.)
What is the idiomatic way to express the same in Elm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an `if` expression. That's really all guards are anyway:

```
case x of 
  _ ->
    if x > 10 then
      ...
    else
      ...
```

In some cases this does result in duplicate `else` branches that could otherwise have been covered by a single `_` branch. The solution to this is the same as for code reuse anywhere else though: Use functions:

```
let 
  default = ...
in
case x of
  Some y ->
    if y > 10 then
      ...
    else
      default
  _ ->
    default
```

(Note that `default` here will be strictly evaluated. If the computation is expensive, add `()` as a dummy argument to evaluate it lazily.)

Why was it removed? Well, I can't read Evan's mind any more that you can, but my guess is because it complicates both the syntax and semantics of `case` expressions.

For example, a common mistake for beginners is to get confused when the compiler complains that a `case` expression isn't exhaustive when they've provided branches with guards that *do* cover all the cases:

```hs
case x of 
  _ | x < 10 -> ...
  _ | x >= 10 -> ...
-- Error: This `case` does not have branches for all possibilities
-- Why u do dis, compiler?
```

The mix of static patterns with exhaustiveness checking and dynamic guard expressions that can use variables and operators is very confusing to many beginners. Many also use `case` expressions with guards instead of *any* `if` expression, just because `case` "feels more functional".

Not having guards therefore makes for a language that is much easier to learn and still just as capable, at the cost of being slightly more verbose in some relatively rare cases.